# Fish's fin got torn in garbage disposal

Tags: health, fish

Putter my fish is two years old. Yesterday while cleaning out his bowl, he jumped out and landed in the sink and fell down the disposal hole with freshly cut potato skins. I managed to get him out within 40 seconds and got him in his holding tank.  I did not want to stress him any further so I left him there overnight.

He has some fin damage and a small scrape on his body which is very shallow. He has been swimming since and this morning he also ate.

Shall I leave him alone and transfer him back to his regular bowl? Shall I be pro-active and treat him for fin rot in case it happens because his fin is damaged?

Comment: What kind of fish? What size? What kind of fin rot treatment do you have? It sounds like he's fine, and fin rot is probably unlikely. I have goldfish and, in this situation, I might give a dose of Melafix (tea tree oil-based medication) to keep any possible bacterial infection in the wound at bay (it's hard to get antibiotics for fish here).

Answer (score 2):

Since he's in a holding tank already, I might just put a bit of Melafix and let him chill in there for a little while longer before transferring him back to his main home.

It's really your call, though.

I would recommend a dose of the Stress Coat, since he was in a yucky place.